# Simple nodejs callback example with fs.readFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to learn async programming and was struggling with lesson 4 of nodeschool.io with the implementation of an async io with callbacks.

Basically, I'm trying to use fs.readFile to count the number of newlines within a file using a callback.

Here's my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pathToFile = process.argv[2];

function counter(callback) {
    var buffer = fs.readFile(pathToFile, function (err, data) {
    var bufferString = buffer.toString();
    var bufferStringSplit = bufferString.split('\n');
  });
  callback();
}

function logMyNumber() {
  console.log(bufferStringSplit.length-1);
}

counter(logMyNumber);
```

I understand that callbacks are executed once the line of code is finished executing, so shouldn't the

```
var bufferString = buffer.toString();
var bufferStringSplit = bufferString.split('\n');
```

be called after fs.readFile() finishes reading the file from disk?

Then finally the callback() calls logMyNumber, which should just output the number of lines the file has.

Comment: Your callback declares a variable `data` but inside your callback you reference `buffer`.  Then, you reference `bufferStringSplit` in another function that isn't declared.  Also, your `callback` in `counter` is called outside the callback from `readFile` so it's going to get executed before `readFile` finishes.  Follow the chain of callbacks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have several issues going on and I'll try to outline them all as best as possible

### Problem 1: Variable scope

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pathToFile = process.argv[2];

function counter(callback) {
  var buffer = fs.readFile(pathToFile, function (err, data) { 
    // Both of the following variables are scoped to the callback of fs.readFile
    var bufferString = buffer.toString(); 
    var bufferStringSplit = bufferString.split('\n'); 
  });
  callback();
}

function logMyNumber() {
  // Because the variables are in a closure above, bufferStringSplit is null here
  console.log(bufferStringSplit.length-1);
}

counter(logMyNumber);
```

#### Solution:

Declare the variables in the module's scope:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pathToFile = process.argv[2];

// These can now be accessed from anywhere within the module
var bufferString, bufferStringSplit;

function counter(callback) {
  fs.readFile(pathToFile, function (err, data) {
    bufferString = data.toString(); 
    bufferStringSplit = bufferString.split('\n'); 
    callback();
  });
}

// bufferStringSplit should no longer return null here
function logMyNumber() {
  console.log(bufferStringSplit.length-1);
}
```

### Problem 2: Callbacks

```
function counter(callback) {
  fs.readFile(pathToFile, function (err, data) {
    bufferString = buffer.toString(); 
    bufferStringSplit = bufferString.split('\n'); 

    // Place the callback WITHIN the other callback, otherwise they run in parallel
    callback();
  });
}
```

### Problem 3: fs.readFile API

`fs.readFile` doesn't return anything, so your `buffer` variable below is `null`

```
function counter(callback) {      
  var buffer = fs.readFile(pathToFile, function (err, data) {
    bufferString = buffer.toString(); 
    bufferStringSplit = bufferString.split('\n'); 
  });
  callback();
}
```

#### Solution:

```
function counter(callback) {      
  fs.readFile(pathToFile, function (err, data) {
    // The data argument of the fs.readFile callback is the data buffer
    bufferString = data.toString(); 
    bufferStringSplit = bufferString.split('\n'); 
  });
  callback();
}
```

Finally, the code should look like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pathToFile = process.argv[2];

var bufferString, bufferStringSplit;

function counter(callback) {
  fs.readFile(pathToFile, function (err, data) {
    bufferString = data.toString(); 
    bufferStringSplit = bufferString.split('\n'); 
    callback();
  });
}

function logMyNumber() {
  console.log(bufferStringSplit.length-1);
}

counter(logMyNumber);
```

Comment: If you want to keep `bufferString` and `bufferStringSplit` out of the global scope, you could all pass them into the callback from `counter`: `callback( bufferString, bufferStringSplit)`.

Comment: @EmptyArsenal This would be something to consider in the browser, however, in node scope is kept local to the module so you don't have to worry about clobbering the global scope.

Comment: @jibsales Good point. Is there a reason why you wouldn't want instantiate the variables in the function and pass it to the callback (besides the fact that there's no need to)?

Comment: I imagine that defining it outside of the function would remove the need for the program to declare a new variable every time the program ran, but if you were potentially processing a number of asynchronous callbacks, that might be dangerous. Right? Or would that not be an issue?

Comment: @EmptyArsenal You are exactly right. If this was a module that was consumed by another, instantiating the variables in the module scope and manipulating them within the various methods of the module could produce some unexpected behaviors. After all, encapsulation is a pillar of good OOP. However, with so many issues in the OP's code, I thought it to be off topic to dive into the specifics of good OOP design.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me. This is my solution.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = process.argv[2];

function count(pFile, callback) {
  fs.readFile(pFile, "utf8", function(err, data){
     callback(data.split("\n").length-1);
  });
}

count(file, console.log);
```

Comment: For some context, this is the official answer given in the npm learnyounode package answer.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to ***treat errors*** as well. Not sure, if it is better to propagate the error in the last callback. I think the functionality is quite basic, but anyway I am propagating errors.

I would also say is more correct to ***delegate*** the ***split*** in the ***last callback*** rather than passing it through an argument or similar.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var myfile = process.argv[2];



function solution(file, callback){
fs.readFile(file, "utf-8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) callback(err);
    callback(null, data)
});
}

function mycallback(err,data){
  if (err) callback(err) console.error(err);
  return data.split('\n').length-1);
}

solution(myfile,mycallback)
```