# Undefined when returning value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've node project.
Root file is `index.js` and file `helper.js`, here I've some helper functions and it imported to `index.js`.
I'm trying to get some data, using function in `helper.js`, but when I calling it in `index.js` it returning `undefined`.
But in `helper.js` everething is OK, `console.log` showing data that I need.
How I can fix this problem?

index.js file content:

```
const helper = require('./helper');

let data = helper.getData();
console.log(data); // undefined
```

helper.js file content:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  getData: () => {
    fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      const allData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(allData); // IS OK!
      return allData;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of async functions

Comment: Look at this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647346/simple-nodejs-callback-example-with-fs-readfile

Comment: Use promise to get the get the object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/#construction):

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  getData: () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if(err){ 
                reject(err);
            } else {
                try {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                } catch(ex){
                    reject(ex);
                }
            }
        });  
    });
  }
}
```

and then:

```
helper.getData().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
}, function(err){
    // here something failed
});
```

The problem is that `fs.readFile` method is asynchronous and will not give you as result any data [check the documentation here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback).

So one option is to use a [Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/#construction) as I did or to use a `callback` as suggested in the answer of @Tatsuyuki Ishi, you can check the docs about `callback` implementation.

Comment: Perfect  well done for posting the code I was too lazy to write

Comment: I deleted my comment after your answer, was lazy to write a promise ;)

Comment: I don't want to bother anyone, but IMHO this is a pretty bad answer, as it only suggests a solution, but does not explain with a single word what the underlying problem is. And, the shown solution is just an arbitrary one from a pool of more - why should I use a promise? I could also go with a callback, e.g.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `fs.readFile` is an asynchronous function and so doesn't return anything.

If you really need it to return something you can use the synchronous version, [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options).

Otherwise - and a better way to do it - would be to have `getData` return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that you can then `resolve` with `allData`.

Answer (score 1):

`readFile` is an asynchronous function, which accepts a callback. You have two options:

1 . Get a callback as parameter in `getData()`.

```
  getData: (callback) => {
    fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      const allData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(allData); // IS OK!
      callback(allData);
    });
  }
```

2 . Use the synchronous version.

```
  getData: () => {
    var data = fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8');
    const allData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(allData); // IS OK!
    return allData;        
  }
```

Of course, you can use Promise which is more beautiful on chaining things,  but it's often used with dependencies like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are returning `allData` from the callback function, not the `getData` function. And since `getData` has no explicit `return`, your `helper.getData()` function will return `undefined` and this value would printed instead of what you wanted.

I suggest using Promise to return the data properly, as in @sand's answer.